# Show that the set of all multilinear maps is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

OK, so I need to show that the set of all multilinear maps is a subspace (of, obviously, the set of all linear maps): i. e., it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. I have no difficulty in showing that the set is not empty. However, I have no idea about how to show that it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. I thought I could do this by simply applying the definitions and then rearranging the terms but nope. Please help!

Comment: Multilinear maps are not linear, and subspaces don't have to be non-empty. Your question would be much more clear if you added some context: clearly define the spaces you're working with and the vector space structures you're putting on them.

Comment: Right. So, basically, what I want to show is (i) that take any multilinear function (over, say, R) and multiply it with a real number and what you get is also multilinear and (ii) that take any two multilinear functions and add them together and what you get is also multilinear.

Comment: So you need to think about what it means to multiply a function by a scalar or to add two functions together, so that the set of functions $V \times \ldots \times V \to \mathbb R$ (if that is indeed your setting - please clarify!) is a vector space and your question makes sense. Once you have appropriately defined these operations, the proof should be straightforward.